# Visual Studio Diagnostics stops with errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, profiling, memory-profiling

I'm trying debug memory usage of a 32 bit C++ native application using the Visual Studio Diagnostics tools.
This application is running for about 5 minutes and consumes (at its peak) more than 3Gb of RAM.
When using the Visual Studio Diagnostics to profile RAM, the application runs correctly (although much slower). I'm taking a few snapshots while it is running.
**When it terminates and I get the following error:**

> Diagnostics session stopped with errors.
>
> There is not enough space on the disk.

No diagnostics are displayed.

#### But there is enough space on the disk (~40Gb).

I thought of attaching to a running process, take a snapshot and detach. However, I couldn't see how to profile RAM by attaching to a running process. I was only able to profile CPU. I'm not sure RAM profiling is supported when attaching to process.

Did anyone see this problem before? Any idea how to work around this?

---

## Update

Eventually I got the data I needed using [UMDH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947(v=vs.85).aspx).
UMDH did the job in a simple and straightforward way, while other tools (I tried "Visual Studio Diagnostics" and "MTuner") failed miserably.